# EIP1271 - signing message as signer

Tags: gnosis-safe, eip-1271

I want to use EIP1271 to sign a message as a signer for a gnosis safe, but unfortunately, the safe says `false`. I tried some things bot nothing really helps, so I thought it could make sense to ask here.

Here is the situation:

- My tests are done on rinkeby.
- offchain implementation is done in javascript with ethers.js
- My safe is in version 1.3.0

I have a message offchain which I sign with `wallet.signMessage(ethers.utils.keccak256(...))`. I send the raw data to a contract and the contract creates a message hash with `ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(keccak256(...))`.

Then I use the openZeppelin signatureChecker to check if the given signature works with the given data, but the signatureChecker always says `false`. When I don't use the safe wallet to check the signature, but use the signer wallet, everything works.

What I checked, so far:

- the created offchain message and the created onchain message are the same. I changed my onchain code a bit to see if the created message fits the one created offchain and they are the same.
- With the help of tenderly simulations, I was able to have a deeper look into what is going on during the function call. It seems like the internal error message in the safe is `GS026` which leads to the error: Invalid owner provided. And indeed, the calculated ownerAddress in the contract is different than the signer address I used to sign the signature.

So at the moment, I have no idea why it is not working. Could It be, that it is not working on rinkeby in general? I think in one question I once saw something that someone sayed, that some safe function are not working on rinkeby.

Some code snippets I use:

createSignature:

```
const signature = await wallet.signMessage(
        ethers.utils.arrayify(
            ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(...)
        )
   )

const contract = new ethers.Contract(signingUtilsContractAddress, signingUtilsContractAbi, provider);
const res = await contract.isValidSignature(rawData, signature, contractAddress);
```

the onchain code is:

```
function isValidSignature(
        Data.Data memory _data,
        Data.Signature memory _signature,
        address _contract
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        require(block.timestamp <= _signature.expiry, "Signature has expired");
        require(_cContract != address(0), "contract is zero address");
        if (_signature.signer == address(0)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            bytes32 message = keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(...)
            );

            return
                SignatureChecker.isValidSignatureNow(
                    _signature.signer,
                    ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(message),
                    _signature.signature
                );
        }
    }
```

**Update**

Based on this: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/test/handlers/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.spec.ts#L86-L94 it seems like my signature creation is wrong. So I changed it to:

```
const signature = await wallet.signMessage(
        ethers.utils.arrayify(
            ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(...)
        )
   ).replace(/1b$/, "1f").replace(/1c$/, "20")
```

but still no luck. The calculated signer address in the safe is different, now. But it still says `false`.

**Update 2**

I changed the signature on behalf of @mikheeevm so that it ends with a 0 byte and something changed.

```
const signature = await wallet.signMessage(
        ethers.utils.arrayify(
            ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(...)
        )
   ).replace(/1b$/, "00").replace(/1c$/, "00")
```

Based on Tenderly, the error now is `GS022: Invalid contract signature location: length not present`. So it's definitely going into the right direction.

one example:

message: `0x120ff11c3c05288e64af4942131a3320120db1644cb019773d329197e5332a72`

signature: `0x930123841f98036d1d05c4cb48780fdfebd841b19a40386d8e5e6e20c25bef963be457b74d7f7e80bd20f4a34e03f509215f3bd350141120da46906e7e09eec300`

This should work on rinkeby

**Update 3**

still no luck. setting `v=0` doesn't seem to be the right way. I want to sign a message from my EOA Wallet, which can be validated with the safe contract. `v=0` doesn't do the trick, since this is only if the safe should validate the signature from another contract. So `v=27` or `v=28` should work for me. Unfortunately I'm still not able to create a correct signature.

It seems like the way how I create the signature is somehow wrong. I tried to reproduce the way how it is done in the safe contract, but this didn't worked.

Then I tried to do it like it is done in the CompatibilityFallbackHandler testcases here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/test/handlers/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.spec.ts#L124 But it didn't worked. Allways the same issue, the recovered ownerAddresss is not the same as the signing address.

Comment: for an eip1271 sig the V (last 1 signature byte) should be 0: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L257

Comment: Can you provide an example signature and message that shows the problem?

Comment: Please share a GitHub gist that displays the example messageHash & signature you are using when calling `isValidSignature` on Gnosis contracts